# Are zero padded width and precision the same for integer arguments to printf?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, printf, number-formatting

I recently stumbled over code like this:

```
uint32_t val;
...
printf("%.08X", val);
```

which is confusing to me. I mean, either specify `0`+width or specify precision, what's the point of both?

[Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/25366k66.aspx):

> The width argument ... controls the minimum number of characters that
>   are output. If the number of characters in the output value is less
>   than the specified width, blanks are added ... . If width is prefixed
>   by 0, leading zeros are added ... .
>
> The width specification never causes a value to be truncated. ...

[Precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/0ecbz014.aspx):

> ... It consists of a period (.) followed by a non-negative decimal
>   integer that, depending on the conversion type, specifies ... the
>   number of significant digits to be output.
>
> The type determines either the interpretation of precision or the
>   default precision when precision is omitted ...
>
> `d, i, u, o, x, X` - The precision specifies the minimum number of
>   digits to be printed. If the number of digits in the argument is less
>   than precision, the output value is padded on the left with zeros. The
>   value is not truncated when the number of digits exceeds precision.

So I'd either use `"%08X"` *or* `"%.8X"` but `"%.08X"` doesn't make any sense to me.

It does however seem that it doesn't make any difference, that is, all three variants seem to produce the same output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct:

`"%08X"`, `"%.8X"` and `"%.08X"`

**are equivalent.**

As for *why* - refer to this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Hence:

In case 1, this one uses specifies the width:

> Minimum number of characters to be printed. If the value to be printed
>   is shorter than this number, the result is padded with blank spaces.
>   The value is not truncated even if the result is larger.

Hence:

`%08X` will print a *minimum of 8 characters*

and from this reference:

> For integer specifiers (d, i, o, u, x, X): precision specifies the
>   minimum number of digits to be written. If the value to be written is
>   shorter than this number, the result is padded with leading zeros. The
>   value is not truncated even if the result is longer. A precision of 0
>   means that no character is written for the value 0. For a, A, e, E, f
>   and F specifiers: this is the number of digits to be printed after the
>   decimal point (by default, this is 6). For g and G specifiers: This is
>   the maximum number of significant digits to be printed. For s: this is
>   the maximum number of characters to be printed. By default all
>   characters are printed until the ending null character is encountered.
>   If the period is specified without an explicit value for precision, 0
>   is assumed.

`%.8X` uses the precision specifier. As such, it too, will also print a minimum of 8 characters.

And lastly:

`%.08X` will also print a minimum of 8 characters (again, because of the precision specifier). Why? Because `08` is interpreted as `8` - resulting in the same output as the previous. This may not seem to make sense for single digit precision specification outputs, but in a case like this:

`%0.15X`

It *can* matter.

**These different formats exist to allow finer control of output** (which in my opinion - is a carry over that resembles Fortran a lot).

However, as you've discovered, this overcompensation for finer control of precision allows you to get the same output - but with different flags.

UPDATE:

As hvd pointed out, which I had forgotten to mention: the `X` specifier requires an unsigned value, so in this case your output is the same for `%08X` and `%.8X` (due to there being no sign). However, for something like: `%08d` and `%.8d` - **it isn't as: one pads to 8 digits, the other to 8 characters, so they behave differently for negative values.**

Comment: That does not answer the question *why* it is defined that way, it just shows that it is. I'd be interested in the OPs question: "...what's the point of both?"

Comment: Note that while `%08X` and `%.8X` mean the same thing, `%08d` and `%.8d` don't: one pads to 8 digits, the other to 8 characters, so they behave differently for negative values. `X` takes an unsigned value, so it never has a sign.